# Why is nothing happening on my CLKOUT pin, despite the RTC working fine?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, mplabx, mplab

I apologize for the (probably) trivial question -- I'm just starting to get back into coding for MCUs after a long hiatus, so please be patient with me.

I'll preface this by acknowledging that there are definitely better / more succinct ways of doing certain operations in my code, but I'm currently focusing on readability until I feel comfortable coding again.

---

What I'm trying to do is simple: I just want to enable the internal 32kHz oscillator in my AVR32DB28 chip ([datasheet here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/AVR32DB28-32-48-DataSheet-DS40002301A.pdf)) and then view this clock signal on the `CLKOUT` pin, `A7`. I'm using MPLAB X IDE, which I've never used before, and I'm setting the "Simulator" as my "Connected Hardware Tool". I'm using the Logic Analyzer to view my `PORTA` signals, which works fine for verifying simple commands like `PORTA.OUT= 0b10111001` and the like. However, in trying to verify the `OSC32K` signal on the `CLKOUT` pin, I'm encountering two problems:

### Problem #1

The code snippet below will not compile, as it says "Unable to resolve identifier CPU", which seems weird since I can see all of the register offsets (as they appear in the datasheet) in the info-popup that appears in the IDE editor when I hover my mouse over this declaration in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/cpufunc.h>    // assuming I need this to interact with CPU register???

#define F_CPU 24000000UL

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    setup();
    schedule();
    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void setup(){
    
    PORTA.DIR = 0xFF; // designate all Port A pins as outputs
    
    CPU.CCP = 0xD8; // unlock protected registers by writing correct key to CCP register (Section 7.6.1 in datasheet)
    
    CLKCTRL.OSC32KCTRLA = 0b10000000; // enable OSC32K to run in standby mode
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = 0b10000010; // enable CLKOUT and choose OSC32K as main clock
    
}

void schedule(){
    while(1){}
}
```

I can get my code to compile by replacing `CPU.CCP = 0xD8` with:

```
volatile unsigned long* cpu_cpp = (volatile unsigned long*)0x34;
*cpu_cpp = 0xD8; // Unlock access to protected CPU registers
```

...which is admittedly code generated by ChatGPT. So even assuming this solves **Problem #1** (which I doubt, and would like confirmation on from you guys), this then leaves me with **Problem #2**:

### Problem #2

Even after I make the aforementioned code replacement, the Logic Analyzer fails to show ANY activity on the `CLKOUT` pin, which leads me to believe that I'm not initializing the clock correctly OR that I need to do something else to get `CLK_MAIN` to appear on the `CLKOUT` pin. I'm certain it's not an issue with the Logic Analyzer setup, as I can easily get an output signal to appear on my other I/O pins using `PORTA.OUT = 0bXXXXXXXX`.

What confuses me is that I can configure the RTC to use `OSC32K`, and then tie this to the output pins on `PORTA` as a type of "pseudo" clock signal, but again, this involves manually invoking `PORTA.OUT = 0bXXXXXXXX` when `RTC.CNT` meets a certain condition, which is not preferable.

I was under the impression that, once I configure `OSC32K` as `CLK_MAIN` in the datasheet, that this would be tied to `CLK_PER` which should inherently appear on `PA7`, or `CLKOUT` (as per the block diagram "Figure 12-1" in the datasheet under Section 12.4.1 for `CLKCTRL`)?

---

Sorry for such a long post. To summarize, let me formulate everything I've said into two questions:

**Question #1:** Why is my compiler not recognizing the `CPU` identifier, while the IDE editor seems to recognize `CPU` and its offset registers like `CPU.CCP` in the context pop-up while hovering my mouse over `CPU.CCP`? Is this line even necessary to modify the control bits for the `CLKCTRL` registers? Is the code replacement written by ChatGPT a viable alternative? What would be the best way to set up `OSC32K` as my main/peripheral clocks, `CLK_MAIN` and `CLK_PER`?

**Question #2:** Once Question #1 has been dealt with, how do I actually go about viewing the `OSC32K` signal on my `CLKOUT` pin? Should it just appear there, or do I need more code to do this? Also, why does `RTC.CNT` seem to work, even though I haven't found a solution to Question #1? Does this perhaps indicate that I actually have correctly configured `OSC32K` as my main clock, and that I'm just missing code to route it to the `CLKOUT` pin?

If you've read this far, thank you -- I'd appreciate any help you can give to a newbie like me. Thanks!

Comment: this is a question and answer site ... please ask a question that can be answered with one answer ... submit new posts for additional questions

Comment: I included multiple questions because they all go hand-in-hand with each other. I can submit six different posts with the same code, or just reference the same code in one post with all relevant questions. Is there a rule against asking multiple related questions in one post? Genuinely curious... Also, most of my questions can all be answered with 1-2 thorough answers, just sayin'

Comment: Maybe try the function `CPPWrite()`

Comment: A reason for question closure is often this: **Needs more focus** - *This question currently includes multiple questions in one*. It should focus on one problem only. And, if you think about it, you might get ten people able to answer part 1 and ten able to answer part 2 and none able to answer both. So, do you really want to cut down the odds of getting any answer?

Comment: As a new member, please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. This is not a forum. And please read "[ask]". Since my following notes do not answer anything, they are just notes.

Comment: As with any IDE, you need to differentiate between the editor of the IDE and the compiler. The editor might recognize `CPU`, but the compiler needs a declaration, and at a later stage the linker the definition. You might want to look for the necessary header file that declares that symbol.

Comment: Each simulator has some shortcomings. Simulating the clock module can be one of them. Does the documentation of the simulator tell that `CLKOUT` is simulated?

Comment: Solution to problem 1 must be wrong. The register is 8-bit. Do not ask ChatGPT to code for you. It's wrong.

Comment: `code replacement written by ChatGPT` ... ChatGPT did not write the code ... somebody else on the internet wrote it ... ChatGPT only found the code without knowing what the code does

Comment: @Andyaka Fair enough, I'll make sure to follow this in future posts

Comment: @thebusybee My mistake, I'll give that a read. Thanks for your notes too, those are helpful to someone new like me. I'm not able to find any info on whether `CLKOUT` is simulated, I might contact MPLAB support

Comment: @Justme Thank you for the confirmation. Full disclosure, it's successfully helped me a bit in Python for solving weird problems, but it seems much less reliable for C. I'll take your advice and avoid.

Comment: @jsotola True. Although I have had it help me with some weird OOP problems in Python for which I found nothing online. It seems to be able to generate novel code and be able to do so based on a given context, so I wouldn't say that it just copies and pastes code blindly. Either way, it seems pretty unreliable with C, so I'll avoid this in the future. Also, I'll take your previous advice and keep future posts shorter, sorry for my previous response to you.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my compiler not recognizing the CPU

It seems like they forgot to add it into .h  file.

But you can use this insted

```c
CPU_CCP =  0xD8;
// or 
CPU_CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
//or 
CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc; 
//or
CCP = 0xD8;
```

> how do I actually go about viewing the OSC32K signal on my CLKOUT pin? Should it just appear there, or do I need more code to do this?

Try to use this code insted your setup function.

```c
void setup(){
        
   PORTA.DIR = 0xFF;                               // all Port A pins as outputs
   CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;                             //unlock protected registers
   CLKCTRL.OSC32KCTRLA =  CLKCTRL_RUNSTBY_bm;      //Run Standby bit
   CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;                             // IO Register Protection 
   CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = CLKCTRL_CLKOUT_bm           //  enable CLKOUT
                      | CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC32K_gc;  // choose OSC32K as main clock 
    }
```

We need to enable CCP every time. Because of this quote from the datasheet:

> Within four instructions, the software must write the appropriate data to the protected I/O register.
> **The protected change is automatically disabled after the CPU executes a write instruction**

Or use this macro

```c
_PROTECTED_WRITE(reg, value); 


_PROTECTED_WRITE(CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA, CLKCTRL_CLKOUT_bm | CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC32K_gc);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't 100% fixed my issue, but I still learned a lot from your post, so thank you for this. I suppose my next course of action would be to just run this program on an MCU and see if the problem is with the IDE Simulator or with the code still.

Also, does anyone know where I can find the .h file that they were supposed to add the CPU identifier? I assume it's something specific to my particular AVR MCU, and not something generic like cpufunc.h?